# How to retrieve values from 4 tables

Tags: sql

Table 1

```
Age   Address   City ID
```

Table 2

```
Name   Address   Pincode ID
```

Table 3

```
Name   Address   Pancard id
```

Table 4

```
Name   Address   Voter Id   Id
```

I want to retrieve values from table 1 and table 2 first and secondly

I want to retrieve value from table 3 and table 4, after that I want retrieve values from the result from table 1 and 2 and table 3 and 4 combined

I want to retrieve age from first table, address from second table, pancard from third table and voterid from the fourth table

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.  Can you also post some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: So what is preventing you from retrieving all of this information according to the rules you've described? Have you tried to retrieve it or just "want" to do it?

Comment: poorly designed table with lots of redundancy. In fact it is gonna make your SQL query have data integrity and inconsistency issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT T1.age, T2.Address, T3.Pancard, T4.Voter_Id 
FROM Table1 T1 JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
JOIN Table3 T3 ON T2.ID = T3.ID
JOIN Table4 T4 ON T3.ID = T4.ID
```